# SQL Lite losing records in a database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have some java code that I am working on and have been running into a strange issue.

I have one master table that uses rowid as the primary key, and contains a record.   This record is inserted then updated as required.   This all works fine.

I have three other tables that store data related to the first table and are referenced by the rowid in the first table.

My issue is when it's time to update the data in the other tables, I typically delete all the records linked to the primary id,  then re-insert them.

However doing this seems to not always insert the records?  even though the data is definitely being sent to the sqlite driver.     The problem is not consistent either, sometimes it adds all the records in the loop, other times it adds two, and finally other times it adds none.. Does this have to do with me deleting the records then re-inserting them?  (does not really make sense)...  or something else entirely?

Given the following query:

```
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: DELETE FROM faction_members WHERE faction_id='1'; 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_members VALUES('1','0f448831-477e-3e62-87aa-bbbdbb2d28ed','0');
```

Then the second table of data:

```
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: DELETE FROM faction_ranks WHERE faction_id='1'; 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_ranks VALUES('1','0','Leader'); 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_ranks VALUES('1','1','General'); 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_ranks VALUES('1','2','Officer'); 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_ranks VALUES('1','3','Member'); 
16.03 21:32:43 [Server] INFO [Database] Query Was: INSERT INTO faction_ranks VALUES('1','4','Recruit');
```

The result that is written to the database is:

```
sqlite> select * from faction_members; <-no results
sqlite> select * from faction_ranks;
1|0|Leader
1|1|General
1|2|Officer
sqlite>
```

Any guesses?  I don't seem to run into this problem using the insert/update approach but when I delete the records, then insert new rows they don't make it into the table reliably.

No errors being reported

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm...  I may have just figured it out.

The delete/insert was being done in a different thread, so I suppose its entirely possible that even though I was calling delete before, it wasn't actually firing first and possibly in the middle of the insertion loop?

Disabled writing on separate threads in my code and all the data appears to be in the database now.